# Want to write a string and path of directory whose type is None into a file

Tags: python, concatenation

I have a path called from a function `pathorganizer` as following.

The function `pathorganizer` looks like following,

```
def pathorganizer(raw,output):
    for root,sub,file in os.walk(raw):
        for folders in sub:
            if folders.startswith("raw"):
                patient_id_raw = root.split(os.sep)[8]
    for outdir,outsub,outfile in os.walk(output):
        for folders in outsub:
            if folders.startswith("raw"):
                patient_id_output = outdir.split(os.sep)[8]
            #print(outdir)   
            if folders.startswith("derived"):
                if patient_id_output == patient_id_raw:
                    path = print(outdir + "/derived/")
                    #path = str(path)
                    return(path)

 pathorganizer(raw,outdir)
         /Users/xyz/temp/pro/data_repo/poc/MAY-M-13/PZT-MAY-2/events/derived/
 type(pathorganizer(raw,outdir))
         /Users/xyz/temp/pro/data_repo/poc/MAY-M-13/PZT-MAY-2/events/derived/
         NoneType
```

And now I need to append the above path(string) to another string. The above string is detected as a NoneType, not as a string. In this case, I am not able to concatenate it with another string. When I try to concatenate it is throwing me following error,

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

Here is what I tried,

```
for sam in list:
    file = sam + '.doc'
    with open(file, 'w') as my_file:
         my_file.write("whatever: "   + pathorganizer(raw,outdir)  + sam + "\n")
```

I would like to know how can I write or concatenate my values in this case.
I am aiming for a `.doc` written as following,

```
 whatever: /Users/xyz/temp/pro/data_repo/poc/MAY-M-13/PZT-MAY-2/events/derived/sam
```

I also tried `str(pathorganizer(raw,outdir))`, then it returns the `doc`

the file is written as,

```
whatever: Nonesam
```

Comment: It seems that the function `pathorganizer` returns `None`. Why do you think that the string `/Users/xyz ... derived/` is involved in this question?

Comment: What exactly is going on with `pathorganizer`? It's not even valid Python syntax.... and what does this have to do with `pandas`?

Comment: How the path '/Users/xyz/temp/pro/data_repo/poc/MAY-M-13/PZT-MAY-2/events/derived/' is of type None?

Comment: The function returns the path, and the data type of the path is `NoneType`, as it says when you do a `type()` on it.

Comment: @Idlehands, what is not even a python syntax there?

Comment: @quamrana The `pathorganizer` returns the path as I mentioned in the question. But the type of the result is NoneType as the error states

Comment: @user1017373: That is patently not true. The function returns `None`. There is no *path*. What do you mean by *path*? And where does the string that I mentioned come into it? Perhaps you need to show the code of the function `pathorganizer`.

Comment: Ok, it is the naming conventions, here the path (or string) is `Users/xyz/temp/pro/data_repo/poc/MAY-M-13/PZT-MAY-2/events/derived/`, and that is what the function `pathorganizer` returns. But python is not taking it as a string, but `Nonetype`.

Comment: Or do you wannna see how the function `pathorganizer ` returns it?

Comment: So the `pathorganizer` is now provided. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `pathorganizer` function can return `None` if the `if` statements fail.

In your case it seems that since the `print` produces an output then the `if` statements have found something.

What is happening here:

`path = print(outdir + "/derived/")`

is that `print` is returning `None` and then:

`return(path)` is returning that `None`.

So in either case your function returns `None`.

Change the last few lines of your function to be:

```
if folders.startswith("derived"):
    if patient_id_output == patient_id_raw:
        return outdir + "/derived/"
```

Comment: Thanks, make sense!   This change is generating the desired output.

Comment: @user1017373: So do you understand what was going wrong and why the above change fixed things?

Comment: Yes, I understood `print` was returning the None and so if I call it in the return obivoulsy it will only return none.

Comment: I think you were fooled by *seeing* the path printed on the screen by the `print` statement. You thought that what you were seeing was what was being returned by the function.